# Access timer creating new "error 5" message

Tags: ms-access, timer, runtime

I'm an Access 365 amateur who created this code on a form.  It's supposed to wait a bit, then open a form that runs several tests:

Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
Me.TextTime.Value = Format(Time, "HH:mm:ss AM/PM")
Static iCount As Integer
    iCount = iCount + 1
        If iCount = 60 Then
            Me.TimerInterval = 0
            DoCmd.OpenForm "TEST FORM"
        If Me.TimerInterval = 0 Then
        Me.TimerInterval = 125
        End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
       
        
End Sub
```

It was working fine, but then for some reason it started producing an e:

Run-Time Error '5': Invalid procedure or call argument.

The debugger highlights this line:

```
If Me.TimerInterval = 0 Then
```

Oddly enough, the procedure still finishes despite the error message.  But of course, I don't want it to appear.    What suddenly became the problem, and how do I resolve this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can reduce it to:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    Static iCount As Integer

    Me.TextTime.Value = Format(Time, "HH:mm:ss AM/PM")

    iCount = iCount + 1
    If iCount = 60 Then
        Me.TimerInterval = 125
        iCount = 0
        DoCmd.OpenForm "TEST FORM"
    End If       
        
End Sub
```